# How do you implement an isLoggedIn method with Angular Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to implement an isLoggedIn method with Firebase on my Angular 6 app, and am running into problems because the firebase user is a "subcription" object, and I am trying to use it like a regular method isLoggedIn().

This is what I have so far:

```
export class AngularFireAuthService {
    private firebaseUser$: Observable<firebase.User>;

    constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.firebaseUser$ = angularFireAuth.authState;
    }

    getFirebaseUser() {
        return this.firebaseUser$;
    }

    register(user: any) {
        return this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    }

    login(user: any) {
        return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    }

    logout() {
        return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut();
    }

    resetPassword(email: string) {
        return this.angularFireAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        //not sure how to do this.

        //I was trying to do something like this:
        // this.firebaseUser$.subscribe((user) => {
        //     if (user) {
        //         return true;
        //     } else {
        //         return false;
        //     }
        // });
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to implement an isLoggedIn method, so that I could just simply call it in any of my components? I tried googling this and it seems like the way most people are doing it is to subscribe to the firebaseUser$ object, and if the result is not null, then assume the user is logged in. But I was wondering if I could get around having to subscribe in each of my components and instead just call a `isLoggedIn` method that would simply return true or false, like this:

```
if (this.angularFireAugthService.isLoggedIn()) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: A user's sign-in state can change between renders, and you'll want to update your UI when that happens. *That* is the reason folks use subscribe. You can certainly use a changed value to determine if the user is logged in when your render loop is called, but you'll miss the updates.

Comment: But how did we do it before we had subscriptions? Like in Angular 1.  I could manually control my views by checking isLoggedIn isn't it?

Comment: In any Angular version the integration is built on top of Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` handler. See the first snippet here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property on the auth service and keep track of it on certain scenarios. If you want to persist authentication on reload you need to create a 'listener' method and to subscribe to it in the root component.

Here is an example:

```
private isAuthenticated: boolean;

public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
     return this.isAuthenticated;
 }

public async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      ...
    } catch (error) {
      this.isAuthenticated = false;
      ...
    }
  }

public async logOut(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut();
      this.isAuthenticated = false;
      ...
    } catch (error) {
       ...
     }
  }

// you subscribe to this in the root component
public initAuthListener(): Observable<User> {
    return this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
      tap(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          // do stuff
        } else {
          this.isAuthenticated = false;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

And in your whatever component you can use:

```js
if (this.angularFireAugthService.isLoggedIn()) {
   //do something
}
```

**Update**

In the `app.component.ts` you need to inject the auth service and subscribe to the `initAuthListener` method in the `OnInit` life cycle hook like so:

```js
constructor(private angularFireAugthService: AngularFireAuthService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.angularFireAugthService.initAuthListener().subscribe();
}
```

Now the authentication will persist and the `isAuthenticated` property from the auth service will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the comment //you subscribe to this in the root component? Do you mean in app.component.ts? Could you show an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase has native function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#web-v8_2) that return userId if already loggin.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
   // ...
 } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
 }
});
```